# lmfit 'Parameters' object has no attribute '_asteval'

Tags: python, python-2.7, lmfit

I have just updated lmfit package to version 0.9.15 in Python 2.7 64b, and the following error is raising when creating a new Parameters object (i.e. `p = lmfit.Parameters()`):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27_64b\lib\site-packages\lmfit\parameter.py", line 65, in __init__
    super(Parameters, self).__init__(self)
  File "C:\Python27_64b\lib\collections.py", line 48, in __init__
    self.update(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Python27_64b\lib\site-packages\lmfit\parameter.py", line 87, in update
    for sym in other._asteval.user_defined_symbols():
AttributeError: 'Parameters' object has no attribute '_asteval'
```

I just tried this example from [link](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/examples/example_emcee_Model_interface.html):

```
import numpy as np
import lmfit
def double_exp(x, a1, t1, a2, t2):
    return a1*np.exp(-x/t1) + a2*np.exp(-(x-0.1) / t2)

model = lmfit.Model(double_exp)
truths = (3.0, 2.0, -5.0, 10.0)
x = np.linspace(1, 10, 250)
np.random.seed(0)
y = double_exp(x, *truths)+0.1*np.random.randn(x.size)
p = model.make_params(a1=4, t1=3, a2=4, t2=3)
```

but it did not work. Therefore I tried to create a Parameters object from lmfit:

```
import lmfit

p = lmfit.Parameters()
```

but it did not work either.

I am using the following versions:

- Python 2.7 64b
- lmfit 0.9.15
- numpy 1.16.5
- uncertainties 3.1.2
- six 1.11.0
- asteval 0.9.16

I would appreciate if you could help me out.

**SOLUTION:**

The problem was the version of Python 2.7. I updated to Python 2.7.17, and now it works!

Pablo.

Comment: Can you show us the code lines?

Comment: I added the code in the question

Answer (score 0):

Please do as follows:

```
pip uninstall lmfit==0.9.15
pip uninstall asteval==0.9.16
```

And Then again install it as following sequence:

```
pip install asteval==0.9.16
pip install lmfit==0.9.15
```